# Interfacing with a 24V IO device

Tags: gpio, relay, communication

I have a UR10 industrial robot arm that I'd like to communicate with using it's IO board with my Pi 3B. I would like the arm to perform a pick and place routine after I detect that some operation is done with the Pi.

Its IO board has a 24V 2A control box. I was thinking that some solid state relays as a 3.3-to-24V level shifter would suffice. This does not have to be instantaneous communication, just a toggle.

Answer (score 1):

You can find IO shield from here https://www.fultek.com.tr/en/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/MainBoard.png

Full project download url: https://www.fultek.com.tr/en/speed-plc/

Comment: This answer as presented looks like a (minimal-effort) product endorsement. Looking deeper suggests it's not, but that's not quite the point.

Answer (score 1):

You are right; relays are your friend.  A little bit of poking around found a relay HAT at Amazon.  I haven't tried this and will not benefit if you try it, but the specifications look right and the reviews are good.  I like the idea of a HAT for your application because you have a sort-of one-piece controller.
[https://www.amazon.com/Raspberry-Pi-Expansion-Module-XYGStudy/dp/B01G05KLIE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01G05KLIE)
I am sure there are other suppliers for this or something similar.